# Master thread slower than other threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a multi-threaded program in C++. I am wondering why if the master thread does part of the computation, it is always (in my test) that the master thread is a couple seconds slower than the rest of the threads. (for comparison other threads run in 9 seconds, master thread run in 11 seconds).

If I don't use the master thread for part of the calculations, all the threads complete at about the same time.  i.e. :

```
int numThreads = 4;
std::thread *threads = new std::thread[numThreads];

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){
   threads[i] = std::thread(func)
}

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){
    threads[i].join();
}
```

vs

```
int numThreads = 4;
std::thread *threads = new std::thread[numThreads - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads-1; i++){
   threads[i] = std::thread(func);
}

func();

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads-1; i++){
   threads[i].join();
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you measure how much time each thread takes?

Comment: I was using boost::timer::cpu. One timer encapsulating the above code, one timer inside the thread. It will return something like [Thread 3]: 8 sec, [Thread 1] 8 sec, [Thread 2] 8 sec, [Thread 0] 11 sec, [Total runtime] 11 sec

Comment: Where exactly? What I'm getting at is that for the main thread timing, you should not be including the thread startup and thread joins at the end in that measurement, only the "func()" call. Otherwise, you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: There are two timers. One measures everything, including thread startup and join calls. One measures the timing of the func(). From the second timer, it shows thread0 is slower than the rest if thread0 is the main thread